# Custom getters and setters in a struct

Tags: rust

How do I create a **custom** getter or setter in a struct:

```
struct MyStruct {
  field1: int
}

impl MyStruct {

  //getter
  fn field1(self) -> int {
    // some calculations....
    // return the value...

  }

  //or
  //setter
  fn field1(self, value) {

  }

}
```

What's the truly Rust way to do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rust does not have anything like Python or C♯ properties at present; `foo.bar` is only ever field access, never a method call. Often it makes sense to just make the field public, but if you don’t want to do that for reasons of safety or needing to have side-effects, having `fn field1(&self) -> int` and `fn set_field1(&mut self, value: int)` would be acceptable.

Comment: In case I go with `fn field1(&self) -> int and fn set_field1(&mut self, value: int)`, how do I make `field1: int` private?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp: it’s private by default. If you wanted it public, you’d need to write `pub field1: int`.

Comment: isn't it private when one accesses from other modules only?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp, yes, Rust only have module-level privacy. Split your program in smaller modules if you need more fine-grained privacy control.

Comment: How about "public may read only"? That would sometimes be useful.

Comment: the ability of a new/custom design datatype to naturally / mathematically engage in expression is paramount for readability (remember, you write it once, then refactor it a hundred times (which is, yes, writing it, again, in a way) but that starts with reading...

Comment: that it would be useful to have properties in rust

Comment: @DanMarinescu: you have not actually demonstrated your point. Technically, properties with custom getters and setters just don’t fit into Rust very easily at all, because of other aspects of the language’s design; a simple implementation like C♯’s, where you just desugar `.x` to `.GetX()` or `.SetX(…)`, would cause quite a lot of surprising and problematic behaviour, so that upgrading a simple property to a custom one would be a breaking change . Further, you currently *know* that `a.b` is cheap: it may do some dereferencing, but that’s all. If it can be arbitrarily complex, life gets harder.

Comment: if you need anything beyond the ability to gracefully engage in expressions, i guess you are right, i did not demonstrate my point at all. getters and setters are considered syntax sugar by blue color java grade language designers (and compiler engineers implementing such things). the only problematic side effects could be related to the functional definition of functions (but these are methods) and functional is conceptually incompatible with oop. i do not need to demonstrate the obvious, not here, nor anywhere else

Comment: every single new/and useful language features was called syntactic sugar by, you know, people. operators overloading, properties (with true setters and getters). they kept calling it that way, while the world moved further. thanks for your kind comments, and yes, you are right, i did not demonstrate my point. should one need to demonstrate the point of true properties with encapsulated getters and setters,  well...

Comment: this is like slashdot splitting hairs

Comment: I am stopping engaging after this one comment (on SO, comments aren’t supposed to be long-form discussions). The two key purposes of custom properties are that you can use them as an lvalue, and that you can upgrade fields to properties backwards-compatibly. Rust’s ownership model and how it handles per-field borrowing scuppers the second of those. Thus, custom properties are impossible in Rust without debilitating and surprising tradeoffs. So get used to `a.b()` and `a.set_b(c)` instead of `a.b` and `a.b = c`, because Rust’s unlikely to ever get custom property syntax.